# Python: Why this code is not making a circle? No error

Tags: python

```
radius=1
for  y in range(0,1001):
    for x in range(0,1001):
        universe=(radius**2)-(x**2)-(y**2)
        if universe>=0:
            print('.')
print('\n')
```

I'm trying to make a circle with just a mathematical function. But this is just giving a output of 3 dot. Whereas, in C++ it's working just fine.

Comment: I don't see how this can work in any programming language. Even ignoring all the other problems, the only couples of values of `x` and `y` that subtracted to 1 give a result higher or equal to 0 are `(x=0, y=0)`, `(x=1,y=0)`, `(x=0, y=1)`, thus the 3 dots printed

Answer (score 0):

Points of a circle must meet x^2 + y^2 <= radius^2. You are using x and y from 0 to 1001 and radius = 1. From all that bunch of numbers only [0.0], [0,1] and [1,0] are "inside" the circle. Try to use a bigger radius or change the x and y vectors.

Answer (score -1):

well, python print will add a new line automatically, to avoid this,
you should use print like `print('.',end='')`